# Java nested if statements

Tags: java, nested-if

I'm using an instantiable class and nested if statements in Java. When I run this it always outputs 500 even when the input is more than 5.

Summer:
less than 5 people is 500,
more than 5 people is 400

Autumn:
less than 5 is 700,
more than 5 is 600

Winter:less than 5 people is 400,
more than 5 people is 300

Spring:
less than 5 is 200,
more than 5 is 100

```
public class Seasons{

//data members
private String season;
private int people;
private int cost;

//constructor
public Seasons(){
season="";
people=0;

}

    //set methods
    public void setSeason(String season){
        this.season=season;
    }

    public void setPeople(int people){
        this.people=people;
    }

    //compute method
    public void compute(){
        if(season.equals ("summer")){
            if(people<=5){
                cost=500;
            }
            else{
                cost=400;
            }
        }


        else if(season.equalsIgnoreCase("autumn")){
            if(people<=5){
                cost=700;
            }
            else{
                cost=600;
            }
        }

        else if(season.equalsIgnoreCase("winter")){
            if(people<=5){
                cost=400;
            }
            else{
                cost=300;
            }
        }
        else if(season.equalsIgnoreCase("spring")){
            if(people<=5){
                cost=200;
            }
            else{
                cost=100;
            }


        }
}




    //get method
    public int getCost(){
        return cost;
    }
}
```

App class:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class SeasonsApp{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        //declare variables
         String season;
         int people;
         int cost;

         //declare objects
         Seasons mySeasons;

         //create objects
         mySeasons=new Seasons();

         //input
         season=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"what season is it");
         people=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many people are going?"));

         //set
         mySeasons.setSeason(season);

         //compute
         mySeasons.compute();

         //get
         cost=mySeasons.getCost();

         //output
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"your cost is " + cost + " euro");


    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear, which initial value `cost` has. Can you clarify on that? And also:   what is the actual value of `season`?

Comment: Share more code. This alone will not say much. What did you initialize cost with? What is the value of seasonr?

Comment: Please post complete code

Comment: You haven't shown us any code that outputs anything, nor how `people` gets its value.

Comment: @ncirl.eva Print the value of `people` in the outer if loop and see for yourself if it is < or > 5.

Comment: step through your code using a debugger

Comment: Madhusudana I haven't done loops yet it works it's just not outputting the else statements I was wondering maybe the brackets aren't in the right places. thanks tho

Comment: @keyser I did says no errors

Comment: @ncirl.eva when he suggested a debbugger it wasn't ment there is an error. A debugger can step through you code line by line and show you all of the values. that how you can see where is the unexpected value accource and why. you can see what was written wrong or what didn't work like you thought

Comment: @Amirag oh I get it now sorry. Where can I debug it?

Comment: I suggest using one of the popular IDEs, e.g. Eclipse or IntelliJ

Comment: @keyser okay thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set the number of people.
Add the line

```
mySeasons.setPeople(people);
```

before

```
mySeasons.compute();
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much I was stuck for hours fixing my if statements :D